# How to resolve Member variable initialization error in haxe program?

Tags: haxe

I'm new in haxe programming, when I build my program it outputs:

`Member variable initialization is not allowed outside of class constructor`

Does anyone know how to solve this, without changing initialization data members?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it might help if you let us know which version of Haxe you are using, and what source code you have that generates the error, preferably in the smallest possible form.

The reason I say this is that the latest Haxe version (3.0.1) I am fairly sure does not ever generate that exact error message... unless I am mistaken :)  So it is hard to know what version you are using and hard to know what the problem might be.

**My guess:** you are using initialization of member variables that is not allowed.  In old versions of Haxe it wasn't allowed at all, in Haxe 3 it is allowed only for "constant" values (strings, ints etc).  I get the error message "Variable initialization must be a constant value" in Haxe 3, but the error message may have changed between versions.

**Broken code**

```
class Initialization
{
    static function main() {
        new Initialization();
    }

    var myInt = 0;
    var myString = "some string";
    var myArray = [1,2,3]; // Error: "Variable initialization must be a constant value"

    public function new() {
        trace(myInt);
        trace(myString);
        trace(myArray);
    }
}
```

**Working code**

```
class Initialization
{
    static function main() {
        new Initialization();
    }

    var myInt = 0;
    var myString = "some string";
    var myArray:Array<Int>; // Define the type, but don't initialize here

    public function new() {
        myArray = [1,2,3]; // Initialize in the constructor
        trace(myInt);
        trace(myString);
        trace(myArray);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: oh, you're on Haxe 2.09.  No inline initializations for you ;)

```
class Initialization
{
    static function main() {
        new Initialization();
    }

    // Define the type, but don't initialize here
    var myInt:Int;
    var myString;
    var myArray:Array<Int>;

    public function new() {
        // Initialize in the constructor
        myInt = 0;
        myString = "some string";
        myArray = [1,2,3];
        trace(myInt);
        trace(myString);
        trace(myArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am creating a project in FlashDevelop with nme 3.3.5 and haxe 2.09. I still dating the same error. My program is similar to the example you put. I can not initialize a data member. Regards

Comment: Hi, Haxe 2.09 does not support initializing member variables outside the constructor. The [changelog](http://haxe.org/file/CHANGES.txt) says it got added in 2.10.  It is a fairly straight-forward, non-breaking upgrade to 2.10 - I would recommend it.  Otherwise you will have to initialize all your values in the constructor.  I'll update my answer with sample code.